# How to check for revocation or deletion of Apple developer P12 certificate?

Tags: ios, ssl

I know I can use OCSP to check if the certificate has been revoked or deleted

```
openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -text -url http://ocsp.digicert.com
```

But Apple's developer certificate P12 does not contain a CA certificate, so it is impossible to detect revocation through this command. Is there any other good way

Comment: You don't need a CA certificate to check if it has been revoked. The OCSP resolver information is included in every certificate (if that CA supports OCSP). Otherwise you have to download the certificate revocation list (CRL) which ca be retrieved from the url denoted in the certificate.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your answer. I don't know much about OCSP. Do you have a demo?I only know that it can be checked by (openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pem -cert wikipedia.pem -text -url http://ocsp.digicert.com), but I don't know how to extract chain.pem and wikipedia.pem from p12